# Configure bun with Azure Devops artifacts package registry

Tags: azure-devops, bun

In my `bunfig.toml` file I have:

```
[install.scopes]
"@company" = {url = "https://company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Web/npm/registry", username = "company", password = "BASE_64_ENCODED_PAT"}
```

Unfortunately I get an error with `SegmentationFault at 0`

Does anyone know how to specifically authenticate with an Azure DevOps based package repository?